# Why won't my Windows 8 desktop icons show?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, windows-8

After I restart my computer and go to my desktop, my startup items begin to load but none of my desktop items load unless I right click for some reason. I'll right click, get the loading icon displayed as my cursor, and 5-10 seconds later the desktop icons show. Anyone know why? I'm running Windows 8 Pro.

Comment: How long have you let it set at the desktop before right clicking?

Comment: Hours. It is only triggered by a right click, I've confirmed.

Comment: Create a new admin user account, log in see if it does the same thing.

Comment: Did you by any chance install Fences on that system? I've seen that happen with the older version of that software....

Answer (score 0):

Use [Soluto](https://www.soluto.com/) or [Spybot](http://www.safer-networking.org/dl/) to modulate your startup items.

Comment: I much perfer CCleaner for the lack of add-on-ware.

Comment: If all you're doing is modifying start up items, a better "diagnostic" is to launch msconfig and disable all startup items, then reenable them one at a time. You can use the same utility to disable services @ startup.

Comment: I prefer Autoruns from Sysinternals.

Answer (score 0):

Malfunctioning profile ALL THE WAY.

Run a chkdsk on the system drive or make a new profile and copy all your stuff over.

system file checker may prove EXTREMELY useful but I would try the first two options I discussed.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old illknown feature in windows:

1. Right-click on your desktop.
2. Select Arrange Icons By.
3. You will see a menu item Show Desktop Icons. Click it to toggle desktop icons on and off.

Answer (score 0):

A full shutdown and restart can sometimes solve this problem.
Type `shutdown /r` on `run` or on commandline.